# Is "offloading a passenger" idiomatic?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english, north-american-english

Merriam-Webster and Oxford seem to suggest that we can offload things, not people, yet "offloading a passenger" is quite prevalent in Philippine English. Is it a phrase that somebody from the inner circle of English speakers would use?

Thanks a lot!

Here are two examples

> *ABS-CBN News* - Melissa Mendez offloaded after 'punching flight attendants'
>
> *Daily Mail* - American Airlines makes emergency landing to offload vomiting female passenger in Texas amid fears she has Ebola... despite not having been in Africa

Comment: You mean with the following meaning? Regular travelers should not be offloaded by executive officers.  .https://opinyonista.wordpress.com/tag/offloading-of-passengers/

Comment: More like this: Melissa Mendez offloaded after 'punching flight attendants' (ABS-CBN News).

Comment: While the "off" component is OK, the inner circle would probably find the "load" part somewhat imprecise as its synonyms---cargo, freight, a consignment, a delivery, a shipment, goods, merchandise---all reference non-human “objects.”

Comment: Disembark is usually used referring to passengers:  to remove or unload (cargo or passengers) from a ship, aircraft, or other vehicle.

Comment: There's evidence of English speakers from the inner circle using this though: Have a look at this title from Mail Online:American Airlines makes emergency landing to offload vomiting female passenger in Texas amid fears she has Ebola... despite not having been in Africa

Read more: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2785065/American-Airlines-flight-makes-emergency-landing-Texas-airport-amid-concerns-female-passenger-displaying-Ebola-like-symptoms.html#ixzz3V6ceQi40
Follow us: @MailOnline on Twitter | DailyMail on Facebook

Comment: Those speakers responsible are no longer members of the inner circle!  :-)

Comment: What do you mean the speaker responsible is no longer a member of the inner circle, Little Eva? The article was written by one David McCormack, a writer for the Daily Mail in the UK.

Comment: offload "**2.** to remove or discharge (cargo, **passengers**, etc.)." TFD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-load [emphasis added]

Comment: In the US I'm sure I've heard "offloading" once or twice to refer passengers, but it's usually reserved for (non-sentient) cargo.  Certainly, using "offloading" in this sense in any formal context would be considered rude.

Comment: @Johs61: Although M-W says *disembark* can be transitive, the transitive use is obsolescent if not obsolete: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+disembarked&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20disembarked%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Offload* is used in the cases you mention to distinguish the action taken from the more commonly used *disembark*.

*Disembark* is the normal word used for people getting off a conveyance (originally ships, but extended to airplanes, trains, buses etc.) but using *disembark* is a little bit ambiguous.

> Jane Doe was disembarked from the 9am flight this morning
>
> Jane Doe was offloaded from the 9am flight this morning

They both mean the same thing, but as it's normal for people to be *disembarked* in a non-forceful way, using *offloaded* for a passenger makes it clearer that the *disembarkation* was against her will rather than the normal procedure.

OED does mention that *off-load* has been used for people.

> **off-load** v. orig. S. Africa (after Du[tch] *afladen*)
>   *trans*. To unload. Also *transf.* and *fig*., to discard, get rid of, relieve oneself of (a person or thing). Hence off-ˈloading *vbl. n.* and *ppl. a.*
>
> **1952** C. Day Lewis tr. *Virgil's Aeneid* v. 113 They enrolled the women for the colony, off-loaded the men who wanted To stay there.

Also compare the definitions from The Free Dictionary and note defn.3 for *offload*.

> **Disembark**
>   v. dis·em·barked, dis·em·bark·ing, dis·em·barks
>   v.intr.
>   1. To go ashore from a ship.
>   2. To leave a vehicle or aircraft.
>   v.tr.
>   To take ashore from a ship.
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disembark
>
> **Offload**
>   v. off·load·ed, off·load·ing, off·loads
>   v.tr.
>   1. To unload (a vehicle or container).
>   2. Computers To transfer (data) to a peripheral device.
>   3. Informal To get rid of and pass on to another
>   v.intr.
>   To unload a vehicle or container.
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offload

Comment: I agree, Frank. I like the term. It's forceful. I just find it strange that none of the major dictionary says we can use "offload" this way.

Comment: @Louel I added a dictionary ref. Offload(3) is probably the definition in use really. I suspect most people who are _offloaded_ are then passed on to another 'authority' to be 'questioned' about why they were _offloaded_.

Comment: @Louel Don't forget that dictionaries only record how a word has been used in the past, they don't actually determine how you can use it. People determine how you can use a word just by using it and making it a popular usage. Dictionaries are very often well behind the times, the OED has entries for common words that haven't been updated for a hundred years.- offload isn't one of them - I'll add an OED quote that shows _offload_ has been used for people.

Comment: shouldn't they have it at least in their online versions, which should include current usage? (Thanks for the examples from the OED--they're good enough for me.)

Comment: @Louel There's over 300,000 words in the OED (and that doesn't include all the variations of words where you can just add some prefix or suffix to make a new word). Noticing that there is a new 'use' for a word is probably the hardest part, then documenting it, then getting into the dictionary (even online) is probably quite an effort. For the most up-to-date dictionaries you need to look at UrbanDictionary or Wiktionary because they are edited by the public and new uses probably appear there first, but because of that you also can't trust them quite as much. (and UD is often rude)

Comment: I love Urban dictionary! :-)

Comment: The OED has some examples of humans being *offloaded* e.g. *1968   M. Woodhouse Rock Baby v. 43   A Director who has to offload one of his staff and is embarrassed.* and 
*2001   FourFourTwo Sept. 104/3   Lazio were prepared to offload Juan Sebastian Veron because they had secured the services of Italian playmaker Stefano Fiore.*

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-load Please scroll down to see "** 2**. to remove or discharge (cargo, **passengers**, etc.). "

Answer (score 5):

The OED has some examples of humans being ***offloaded*** e.g.:

*1968   M. Woodhouse Rock Baby v. 43   A Director who has to offload one of his staff and is embarrassed.* and,

*2001   FourFourTwo Sept. 104/3   Lazio were prepared to offload Juan Sebastian Veron because they had secured the services of Italian playmaker Stefano Fiore.*

But the OED doesn't have any examples of persons being *offloaded* from public transport vehicles.

I would nonetheless adjudge *offload* an appropriate idiomatic use, though it does carry a very slight implication of it being done against the passenger's will. (Though I can well imagine that in internal airline jargon they talk about *offloading passengers* in regular context.) But *disembark* would be more polite when speaking to the public, and points more to it being at the passenger's request or convenience